# Two approaches to writing functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am asking this question in the context of the C language, though it applies really to any language supporting pointers or pass-by-reference functionality.

I come from a Java background, but have written enough low-level code (C and C++) to have observed this interesting phenomenon. Supposing we have some object X (not using "object" here in the strictest OOP sense of the word) that we want to fill with information by way of some other function, it seems there are two approaches to doing so:

1. Returning an instance of that object's type and assigning it, e.g. if X has type T, then we would have:
   `T func(){...}`

   `X = func();`
2. Passing in a pointer / reference to the object and modifying it inside the function, and returning either `void` or some other value (in C, for instance, a lot of functions return an `int` corresponding to the success/failure of the operation). An example of this here is:

   `int func(T* x){...x = 1;...}`

   `func(&X);`

My question is: in what situations makes one method better than the other? Are they equivalent approaches to accomplishing the same outcome? What are the restrictions of each?

Thanks!

Comment: if your function will definitely succeed(which is rare in the C world), `1` and `2` are equivalent. if not, `2` returns error code too. in shorts, `2` is more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a reason that you should always consider using the second method, rather than the first. If you look at the return values for the entirety of the C standard library, you'll notice that there's almost always an element of *error handling* involved in them. For example, you have to check the return value of the following functions before you assume they've succeeded:

- `calloc`, `malloc` and `realloc`
- `getchar`
- `fopen`
- `scanf` and family
- `strtok`

There are other non-standard functions that follow this pattern:

- `pthread_create`, etc.
- `socket`, `connect`, etc.
- `open`, `read`, `write`, etc.

Generally speaking, a return value conveys a number of items successfully read/written/converted or a flat-out boolean success/fail value, and in practice you'll almost always need such a return value, unless you're going to `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` at any errors (in which case I would rather not use your modules, because they give me no opportunity to clean up within my own code).

There are functions that don't use this pattern in the standard C library, because they use no resources (e.g. allocations or files) and so there's no chance of any error. If your function is a basic translation function (e.g. like `toupper`, `tolower` and friends which translate single character values), for example, then you don't need a return value for error handling because there are no errors. I think you'll find this scenario quite rare indeed, but if that is your scenario, by all means use the first option!

In summary, you should always highly consider using option 2, reserving the return value for a similar use, for the sake of consistent with the rest of the world, and because you might later decide that you need the return value for communicating errors or number of items processed.

Answer (score 1):

Method (1) passes the object by value, which requires that the object be copied. It's copied when you pass it in and copied again when it's returned. Method (2) passes only a pointer. When you're passing a primitive, (1) is just fine, but when you're passing an object, a struct, or an array, that's just wasted space and time.

In Java and many other languages, objects are always passed by reference. Behind the scenes, only a pointer is copied. This means that even though the syntax looks like (1), it actually works like (2).

Comment: not necessary. for example, `gcc` implements it, by implicitly prepending a pointer argument to the function prototype, and implicitly pass in the address of the return value. in this implementation, no extra copy is made.

Answer (score 1):

In method 2, we call `x` an *output parameter*. This is actually a very common design utilized in a lot of places...think some of the various built-in C functions that populate a text buffer, like `snprintf`.

This has the benefit of being fairly space-efficient, since you won't be copying structs/arrays/data onto the stack and returning brand new instances.

A really, really convenient quality of method 2 is that you can essentially have any number of "return values." You "return" data through the output parameters, but you can also return a success/error indicator from the function.

A good example of method 2 being used effectively is in the built-in C function `strtol`. This function converts a string to a `long` (basically, parses a number from a string). One of the parameters is a `char **`. When calling the function, you declare `char * endptr` locally, and pass in `&endptr`.

The function will return either:

- the converted value if it was successful,
- 0 if it failed, or
- `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` if it was out of range

**as well as** set the `endptr` to point to the first non-digit it found.

This is great for error reporting if your program depends on user input, because you can check for failure in so many ways and report different errors for each.

If `endptr` isn't `null` after the call to `strtol`, then you know precisely that the user entered a non-integer, and you can print straight away the character that the conversion failed on if you'd like.

Like Thom points out, Java makes implementing method 2 simpler by simulating pass-by-reference behavior, which is just pointers behind the scenes without the pointer syntax in the source code.

To answer your question: I think C lends itself well to the second method. Functions like `realloc` are there to give you more space when you need it. However, there isn't much stopping you from using the first method.

Maybe you're trying to implement some kind of immutable object. The first method will be the choice there. But in general, I opt for the second.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got you.

These to approach are very different.
The question you have to ask your self when ever you trying to decide which approach to take is :

Which class would have the responsibility?

In case you passing the reference to the object you are decapul the creation of the object to the caller and creating this functionality to be more serviceability and you would be able to create a util class that all of the functions inside will be stateless, they are getting object manipulate the input and returning it.

The other approach is more likely and API, you are requesting an opperation.

For an example, you are getting array of bytes and you would like to convert it to string, you would probably would chose the first approch.

And if you would like to do some opperation in DB you would chose the second one.

When ever you will have more than 1 function from the first approch that cover the same area you would encapsulate it into a util class, same applay to the second, you will encapsulate it into an API.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: take `2` if you don't have a necessary reason to take `1`.

Long answer: In the world of C++ and its derived languages, Java, C#, exceptions help a lot. In C world, there is not very much you can do. Following is an sample API I take from CUDA library, which is a library I like and consider well designed:

```
cudaError_t cudaMalloc (void **devPtr, size_t size);
```

compare this API with `malloc`:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

in old C interfaces, there are many such examples:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

I would argue to the end of the world, the interface CUDA is providing is much obvious and lead to proper result.

There are other set of interfaces that the valid return value space actually overlaps with the error code, so the designers of those interfaces scratched their heads and come up with not brilliant at all ideas, say:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

a daily function like reading a file content is restricted by the definition of `ssize_t`. since the return value has to encode error code too, it has to provide negative number. in a 32bit system, the max of `ssize_t` is 2G, which is very much limited the number of bytes you can read from your file.

If your error designator is encoded inside of the function return value, I bet 10/10 programmers won't try to check it, though they really know they should; they just don't, or don't remember, because the form is not obvious.

And another reason, is human beings are very lazy and not good at dealing if's. The documentation of these functions will describe that:

if return value is `NULL` then ... blah.

if return value is `0` then ... blah.

yak.

In the first form, things changes. How do you judge if the value has been returned? No `NULL` or `0` any more. You have to use `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE1`, `FAILURE2`, or something similar. This interface forces users to code more safer and makes the code much robust.

With these macro, or enum, it's much easier for programmers to learn about the effect of the API and the cause of different exceptions too. With all these advantages, there actually is no extra runtime overhead for it too.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming we are talking about returning only *one* value from the function.)

In general, the first method is used when type `T` is relatively small. It is definitely preferable with scalar types. It can be used with larger types. What is considered "small enough" for these purposes depends on the platform and the expected performance impact. (The latter is caused by the fact that the returned object is copied.)

The second method is used when the object is relatively large, since this method does not perform any copying. And with non-copyable types, like arrays, you have no choice but to use the second method.

Of course, when performance is not an issue, the first method can be easily used to return large objects.

---

An interesting matter is optimization opportunities available to C compiler. In C++ language compilers are allowed to perform Return Value Optimizations (RVO, NRVO), which effectively turn the first method into the second one "under the hood" in situations when the second method offers better performance. To facilitate such optimizations C++ language relaxes some address-identity requirements imposed on the involved objects. AFAIK, C does not offer such relaxations, thus preventing (or at least impeding) any attempts at RVO/NRVO.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain :) 
Let say you have to load a giant rocket into semi,

- Method 1)
   Truck driver places a truck on a parking lot, and goes on to find a hookers, you are stack with putting the load onto forklift or some kind of trailer to bring it to the track.
- Method 2)
  Truck driver forgets hooker and backs truck up right to the rocket, then you need just to push it in.

That is the difference between those two :)
. What it boils down to in programming is:

- Method 1)
  Caller function reserves and address for called function to return its return value to, but how is calling function going to get that value does not matter, will it have to reserve another address or not does not matter, I need something returned, it is your job to get it to me :). So called function goes and reserves the address for its calculations and than stores the value in address then returns value to caller. So caller goes and say oh thank you let me just copy it to the address I reserved earlier.
- Method 2)
  Caller function says "Hey I will help you, I will give you the address that I have reserved, store what ever calculations you do in it", this way you save not only memory but you save in time.

And I think second is better, and here is why:

---

So let say that you have struct with 1000 ints inside of it, method 1 would be pointless, it will have to reserve 2*100*32 bits of memory, which is 6400 plus you have to copy it to first location than copy it to second one. So if each copy takes 1 millisecond you will need to way 6.4 seconds to store and copy variables. Where if you have address you only have to store it once.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent to me but not in the implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

int funn(int *x){
    *x=1;
    return 777;
}

int main(void){
    int sx,*dx;
    /* case static' */
    sx=func(4,6); /* looks legit */
    funn(&sx); /* looks wrong in this case */
    /* case dynamic' */
    dx=malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(dx){
        *dx=func(4,6); /* looks wrong in this case */
        sx=funn(dx); /* looks legit */
        free(dx);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In a static' approach it is more comfortable to me doing your first method. Because I don't want to mess with the dynamic part (with legit pointers). 
But in a dynamic' approach I'll use your second method. Because it is made for it.
So they are equivalent but not the same, the second approach is clearly made for pointers and so for the dynamic part.

And so far more clear ->

```
int main(void){
    int sx,*dx;
    sx=func(4,6);
    dx=malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(dx){
        sx=funn(dx);
        free(dx);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

than ->

```
int main(void){
    int sx,*dx;
    funn(&sx);
    dx=malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(dx){
        *dx=func(4,6);
        free(dx);
    }
    return 0;
}
```